# SLD - Is it possible to create a Rule that stylise only the first and last point of a Line?

Tags: geoserver, sld, line

I've read the SLD doc, but I can't find any clue on how to create an SLD file to add a graphic symboliser on the first and last point of a line.

Does someone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example in the GeoServe documentation which seems to do what you need - see http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/geometry-transformations.html#start-and-end-point

[image]

Basically you need to use the startPoint and endPoint functions to extract the start and end point of your line.

```
<PointSymbolizer>
  <Geometry>
    <ogc:Function name="startPoint">
      <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
    </ogc:Function>
  </Geometry>
  <Graphic>
    <Mark>
      <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
      <Stroke>
        <CssParameter name="stroke">0x00FF00</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.5</CssParameter>
      </Stroke>
    </Mark>
    <Size>8</Size>
  </Graphic>
 </PointSymbolizer>
 <PointSymbolizer>
   <Geometry>
     <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
       <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
     </ogc:Function>
   </Geometry>
   <Graphic>
     <Mark>
       <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
       <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">0xFF0000</CssParameter>
       </Fill>
     </Mark>
     <Size>4</Size>
   </Graphic>
 </PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. I Thought transformation functions were for spatial transformation ;)